# How to inflate a recyclerview in a fragment

Tags: c#, android, android-fragments, xamarin, xamarin.android

i am transitioning to tabs in my application and i am trying to convert my recyclerview to show in my tablayout with a viewpager.My problem is that it doesn't show the data that i add with my code.Only the initial layout of the xml file which contains the template of each duplicated row.

MainActivity.cs

```
 protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


            mRecyclerView = FindViewById<RecyclerView>(Resource.Id.recyclerView);

            mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
            mRecyclerView.SetLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);
            game = new List<Models.MatchHistoryListView>();
            mAdapter = new MatchListCustomAdapter(game, mRecyclerView);
            mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);
            viewPager = FindViewById<ViewPager>(Resource.Id.main_viewpager);

            setupViewPager(viewPager);
            tabLayout = FindViewById<TabLayout>(Resource.Id.main_sliding_tabs);
            tabLayout.SetupWithViewPager(viewPager);

            var trans = SupportFragmentManager.BeginTransaction();
            trans.Add(Resource.Id.main_fragmentContainer, new matchHistoryFragment(), "matchHistoryFragment");
            trans.Commit();
}
  public void addData()
{
game.Add(new Models.MatchHistoryListView()
                {
                    Name = "" + mclass.summonerId[0, i],
                    ChampionId = mclass.championId[0, i],
                    Id = mclass.recentGamesId[i],
                    Score = mclass.summonerScoreText[i],
                    championPortraito = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/champion/" + mclass.championName[0, i] + ".png"),
                    Item0 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 0] + ".png"),
                    Item1 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 1] + ".png"),
                    Item2 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 2] + ".png"),
                    Item3 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 3] + ".png"),
                    Item4 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 4] + ".png"),
                    Item5 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 5] + ".png"),
                    Item6 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/item/" + mclass.summonerItems[i, 6] + ".png"),
                    Spell1 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/spell/" + mclass.summonerSpellName[i, 0] + ".png"),
                    Spell2 = new Uri("http://ddragon.leagueoflegends.com/cdn/6.24.1/img/spell/" + mclass.summonerSpellName[i, 1] + ".png"),
                    goldEarned = MyClass.goldEarned[i],
                    minionsKilled = MyClass.minionsKilled[i],

                    MapName = mclass.mapId[i],
                    listViewDrawable = winorlose



                });
             mAdapter.NotifyDataSetChanged();

        mRecyclerView.SetAdapter(mAdapter);

  }
.....................bunch of code here...............


private matchHistoryFragment matchHistoryFrag;
        private Fragment1 frag1;

        private void InditialFragment()
        {
            matchHistoryFrag = new matchHistoryFragment();
            frag1 = new Fragment1();
            // moreFrg = new More();
            //todoFrag = new Todo();
        }
        public void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager)
        {
            InditialFragment();
            ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(SupportFragmentManager);


            adapter.addFragment(matchHistoryFrag, "Match History");
            adapter.addFragment(frag1, "Frag1");
            viewPager.Adapter = adapter;
        }
```

MatchListCustomAdapter.cs (simplified a little the code to make it smaller)

```
public class MatchListCustomAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter
    {
        public Context spaghettiContext;
        MainActivity mainAct = new MainActivity();
        public Activity activity;
        private List<App2.Models.MatchHistoryListView> mgame;
        private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
        private MyClass mclass = new MyClass();
        public MatchListCustomAdapter(List<Models.MatchHistoryListView> game,RecyclerView recyclerView)
        {

            this.mgame = game;
            mRecyclerView = recyclerView;
        }
        public class MyView : RecyclerView.ViewHolder
        {
            .....objects declared here....


            public MyView(View view) : base(view)
            {

                mMainView = view;


            }


        }
        public override int ItemCount
        {
            get
            {
                return mgame.Count;
            }
        }


        public override RecyclerView.ViewHolder OnCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType)
        {
            View row = LayoutInflater.From(parent.Context).Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecentGamesList, parent, false);
            ......finding the objects here......
            MyView view = new MyView(row) { .....sets the objects here....};
            return view;

        }

        public override void OnBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position)
        {

            MyView myHolder = holder as MyView;

            myHolder.mMainView.Click += (s,e) =>
            {
                 .....function here........

            };
            .......Setting the values here.......
        }

    }
```

matchHistoryFragment.cs

```
namespace App2.Droid.Resources.layout.Fragments
{
    public class matchHistoryFragment : Android.Support.V4.App.Fragment
    {

        public override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // Create your fragment here
    }

    public override View OnCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Use this to return your custom view for this Fragment
        return inflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.RecentGamesList, container, 
    }
}
```

}

Comment: you did not show code where you add data?

Comment: I updated my OP

Comment: I dont see you telling your adapter that you added anything.. you need to call notifyDataSetChanged() on adapter once you have added smth

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/recyclerview/#Notifying_RecyclerView_of_Data_Changes

Comment: @OlegBogdanov yep i have it on my code next to the game.Add().WIll update my OP.Sry for the misunderstanding.I am trying not to fill the whole page with code

Comment: you dont need to set adapter again and again

Comment: @OlegBogdanov setting the adapter again after adding the data fixes a weird bug that executes the code twice on my Click eventhandler when clicking on one of the rows after updating the data.I have it so when you click on one of the rows,it opens a new activity with more info.When i update the data on the rows and click again,it opens two activities but setting the adapter again solves that problem

Comment: well I dont know what you are fixing but you have to notify adapter AFTER you set it not before